# Xcode10 Not Support "xcodebuild -dry-run" Command?

Tags: command-line, command, xcodebuild, xcode10

when I update my Xcode 9 to Xcode 10 and run command:
**xcodebuild -dry-run**

I got this error:
**Build system information

error: -dry-run is not yet supported in the new build system**

my environment:
Xcode 10.0
Build version 10A255
MacOS 10.13.6

Here is my question:
Is -dry-run not supported in Xcode 10 and latter?
But I still find "-dry-run" description in "xcodebuild -h" help document, why?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try adding -UseNewBuildSystem='NO' to your xcodebuild line.

Comment: this option works for me ! thank you very much!

Comment: this same undocumented option xcodebuild -UseNewBuildSystem=NO fixes problem where xcodebuild reports "Using new build systemerror: Could not delete because it was not created by the build system and it is not a subfolder of derived data."